# Having trouble installing Ubuntu Phone SDK

Tags: 13.10, ubuntu-touch, ppa, ubuntu-sdk, ide

I've been trying to install Ubuntu Touch development software, and tried installing the packages by trying these two commands:

```
    sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-sdk-team/ppa
```

as well as

```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install ubuntu-sdk
```

After it the shell prints a bunch of outputs, I get these two error messages:

```
    E: Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily      unavailable)
    E: Unable to lock the administration directory (/var/lib/dpkg/), is another process using it?
```

I also tried using this command with it:

```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

but to no avail.

I am using a Samsung ATIV Book 7 740U3E laptop,  and am running Ubuntu through a live disk, which is loaded with Ubuntu 13.10 Saucy Salamander. Could the live disk be the problem? Do I need to fully install Ubuntu on my system for the SDK to work? Do I need to download anything else before the SDK and IDE? Is this normal?

Comment: Please, could you put some of your time to read http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case, it seems that another process (another package manager) uses the `dpkg` lock file. Try to close the `Software Center` or `Synaptic` and try again. You could also just restart your session and just open a terminal to setup again the SDK ppa.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't want to fully install Ubuntu alongside Windows, so running the SDK from a live disk is just more convenient in terms of storage.